# Affine Kodaira dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

In the study of projectice varieties, the Kodaira dimension is a very important invariant associated to a projective variety. For instance, the classification of curves may completly be expressed in terms of the Kodaira dimension. My question is if the Kodaira dimension is also as useful in the affine case, or if there exists a suitable adaption to the affine case.

Comment: One solution to this would be to compactifiy $\text{Spec} A$ and then consider the Kodaira dimension of this projective space. Since the Kodaira dimension is a birational invariant, this would be well-defined. However, this wouldn't be computatble intrinsically in homological information of $A$ would it?

Comment: Iitaka defined logarithmic Kodaira dimension of varieties which are not necessarily projective. It has many desirable properties.